# Chrome Extension Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am aware there are similar questions but I have yet to find one that solves my issue

Basically I am trying to send a message from my background.js script to my content.js script like so

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {

  // Listen for when a user is on correct site and enable the extension
  chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(() => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, ([{ id }]) => {
      chrome.pageAction.show(id);
    });
  }, { url: [{ urlMatches: 'website.com' }] });

  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    checkUrl(tab);
  });

  chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(() => {
    checkUrl();
  });

  chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener((tab) => {
    checkUrl(tab);
  });
});

// Check to see if current url is either website or website1
const checkUrl = (tab = null) => {
  if (!tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      tab = tabs[0];
      if (tab.url.includes('website')) {
        getInfo(tab);
      } else if (tab.url.includes('website2')) {
        getOtherInfo();
      }
    });
  } else if (tab) {
    if (tab.url.includes('website')) {
      getInfo(tab);
    } else if (tab.url.includes('website2')) {
      getOtherInfo();
    }
  }
}

const getInfo = (tab) => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { text: 'report_back' }, (result) => {
    console.log('report_back', result);
  });
}

const getOtherInfo = () => {

}
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log(msg);
  if (msg.text === 'report_back') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      sendResponse(document);
    }, 10000);
  }
});
```

but every time I navigate to the correct pages I get the following errors in the `background.js` console

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

and my console.log is `tabs undefined`

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I am now doing it the exact same was as specified in the [official messaging docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
      "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
      "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello") {
      sendResponse({ farewell: "goodbye" });
    }
    return true;
  });
```

and its not working.. what am I doing wrong?

I've even tried wrapping the sendResponse in a `setTimeout()` but still no change

```
if (request.greeting == "hello") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        sendResponse({ farewell: "goodbye" });
      }, 10000);
      return true;
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

Ive tried re-running the function if there is an error

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { greeting: "hello" }, function (response) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log('error');
        setTimeout(getInfo, 1000);
      } else {
        console.log(response.farewell);
      }
    });
  });
```

and I get error repeatedly

[image]

any help would be appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: which line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: 1) To use sendResponse in an asynchronous code like setTimeout you need `return true` inside your `if` block, see [Chrome Extension Message passing: response not sent](//stackoverflow.com/a/20077854), 2) You can't send DOM elements via messaging. Only JSON-compatible simple types can be transferred. Extract the info as text/number and send it in a simple object/array.

Comment: @wOxxOm so If I put return true after send message, and send JSON back this should work??

Comment: @Bravo not sure 100% I assume its on the sendMessage or the message listener

Comment: doesn't the error in the developer console tell you what code threw it?

Comment: Uhm, there are lots of examples, this is a known peculiarity of the API. In your case: if (msg.text === 'report_back') {  setTimeout(() => { sendResponse(document); }, 10000); return true; }

Comment: Note, if you load [WebExtension polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/) you can use modern async/await syntax with messaging instead of this arcane legacy "return true" kludge.

Comment: @wOxxOm adding return true; didnt seem to change anything getting the same error

Comment: @Bravo its coming from the background.js

Comment: @wOxxOm are you able to post an answer demonstrating the use of the WebExtension polyfill in my situation

Comment: You've placed `return true` in the wrong place. Make sure you understand what it does, which will help you use it in the right place, see the answer and documentation I've linked above. I've also shown the correct place in my comment with code above...

Comment: @wOxxOm no matter where I put that `return true;` it still fails

Comment: Assuming you really did put it in the right place, there must be something else at play here, not obvious from the question. I won't be able to help without trying the extension myself.

Comment: @SmokeyDawson Did you find a solution yet ? I too tried a lot of things and then tried the example from the google docs, but still getting the same message.

Comment: @Priyanshu I was unable to find a solution so I used a work around